# Problem with OnClick event signature in C++Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, timage, tobject

I would like to create a function which replaces the current image with another one. The problem is that I have 64 pictures to replace. I created a function with a `TImage* Sender` parameter but it works only when I set `Sender` as `TObject*` instead.

How can I change this function:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Sender->Picture->LoadFromFile("puste.bmp");
}
```

into this

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1Click(TImage *Sender)
{
    Sender->Picture->LoadFromFile("puste.bmp");
}
```

I am using the VCL library.

Comment: what library are you using? The tag says VCL, but I know at least 3 different frameworks that use a `T` prefix

Comment: Yes, it is VCL library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the signature of the event handler.  It has to be what the VCL expects it to be, which in this case is defined by the [`TNotifyEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent) type, which is what the [`OnClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnClick) event is declared as:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TNotifyEvent)(System::TObject* Sender);

__property System::Classes::TNotifyEvent OnClick = {read=FOnClick, write=FOnClick, stored=IsOnClickStored};
```

However, you don't need to change the signature.  All VCL components derive from `TObject`, and the `Sender` parameter points to the control that was clicked on.  So, in this case, you can simply use a type-cast to access functionality that is specific to `TImage`, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    static_cast<TImage*>(Sender)->Picture->LoadFromFile("puste.bmp");
}
```

You can then assign this 1 handler to all 64 of your `TImage` controls.

If you need to differentiate between different `TImage` controls, you can use the `TImage`'s `Name` or `Tag` property for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much!